# APNS BadDeviceToken 404: Apple Ios push notification for Developement

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

Hello apple Ios APNS guys,
I am facing an picular error response as Status code :400 ad Description:Bad request

```
HTTP/2 400 apns-id: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX {"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}400
```

My app enviroment:
1.ionic framework
2. ionic plugin:[pushNotificationsV5](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotificationsV5/)
3.Xcode 7.1 (appl editor)

my php code as instructed [here](http://coding.tabasoft.it/ios/sending-push-notification-with-http2-and-php/)

```
function sendHTTP2Push($http2ch, $http2_server, $apple_cert, $app_bundle_id, $message, $token) {

    $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    // url (endpoint)
    $url = "{$http2_server}/3/device/{$token}";

    // certificate
    $cert = realpath($apple_cert);

    // headers
    $headers = array(
        "apns-topic: {$app_bundle_id}",
        "User-Agent: My Sender"
    );

    // other curl options
    curl_setopt_array($http2ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "{$url}",
        CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
    ));

    // go...
    $result = curl_exec($http2ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception('Curl failed with error: ' . curl_error($http2ch));
    }

    // get respnse
    $status = curl_getinfo($http2ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $duration = round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $milliseconds;

//    echo $duration;

    return $status;
}

// open connection
if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
    define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
}
$http2ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($http2ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);

// send push
$apple_cert = '/certificates/samplepush/XXXXXX.pem';
$message = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hi!","sound":"default"}}';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$http2_server = 'https://api.development.push.apple.com';   // or 'api.push.apple.com' if production
$app_bundle_id = 'com.abc.xyz';

// close connection
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $status = sendHTTP2Push($http2ch, $http2_server, $apple_cert, $app_bundle_id, $message, $token);
    //echo "Response from apple -> {$status}\n";
    echo $status;
}

curl_close($http2ch);
```

**Note : i have changed credential based id and token.**

I have generated my .pem file step by steps and which are correct and  device token are saved in  my PHP server.
but getting error.

ionic code as 
hi@bobby i am using the cordova push notification plugin   and my code is

```
// push notification start  
        var gcmId=0;
        var iosId=0;
          var options = {
            android: {
              senderID: "867557584587",
              icon:"alert",

            },
            ios: {
              alert: "true",
              badge: "true",
              sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {}
          };

          //localStorage.getItem('gcmRegId')
          // initialize
          $cordovaPushV5.initialize(options).then(function() {
            // start listening for new notifications
            $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
            // start listening for errors
            $cordovaPushV5.onError();


            // register to get registrationId
            $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function(data) {
                //alert("GCM"+data);
                // if Android device.
               if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
                gcmId= data;
                //alert("data"+gcmId);
                }
                // if ios device.
               if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()){
                iosId= data;
               }


            })
          });
```

Comment: What is the url you are using ? It looks like you sending a Prod Notification on Sandbox token

Comment: hi@bobby i am using the cordova push notification plugin and question is modified please.

Comment: I never used Cordova/Ionic, and I didn't see any URL here to know which gateway is called

Comment: Dear @bobby here is the apple server url: $http2_server = 'https://api.development.push.apple.com';

Comment: Are you testing on your own device, or with an app coming from appstore / in house / ad hoc ?